# On certain probability distribution

Tags: probability-theory

I am curious about if there is a simple example illustrating that there is a probability distribution $F$ such that, if $X$ follows $F$, $\mathbb{E}[X^m]<\infty$ for all $m\geq 1$, and decays slower than exponential of any order, i.e. for any $\delta>0$, $\mathbb{E}[\exp(tX^\delta)]=\infty$ holds for all $t>0$?

Comment: what is decaying?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take density $f(x) = c e^{-\ln^2 x} = c x^{-\ln x}$ for $x > 1$, choosing the appropriate constant $c$ to make this a probability measure (turns out $c = 2\,{\frac {{{\rm e}^{-1/4}}}{\sqrt {\pi } \left( 1+{\rm erf} \left(1/2
\right) \right) }}
$ according to Maple).  Since $x^m f(x) = c x^{m-\ln x} < c x^{-2}$ for $x$ sufficiently large. $\mathbb E[X^m] < \infty$.  But for any $t, \delta > 0$, 
$$ \exp(t x^\delta) f(x) = \exp(t x^\delta - \ln^2 x) > 1$$ for $x$ sufficiently large, so $\mathbb E[\exp(t X^{\delta})] = \infty$.